# google map api is not working and doesn't display the map

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, api-key

i have a PHP code that i need to embedded a Google map inside of it  in order to plot markers in future.

for this reason i tried to get a API key for the Google Map and place it inside the code in javascript.

but it did not display anything . how can i fix this problem.

## code:

```
<?php
        /*
        Template Name: search info_location
        */

        get_header();
          ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Custom Markers</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key= AIzaSyBSpBVcEmUnLMXS1wN9Mx8JcOhWvLA0kvY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
     <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 400px;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">

         var map,currentPopup;
         function initMap() 
         {
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.888630, 35.495480),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
         });
       }
        </script>
     </body>
</html>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: `callback=initMap` - where is your `initMap` function? How does google maps API know where you want to have a map?

Comment: it my mistake i did not add to the question the initMap function but even so it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tried your code its working fine i believe you got some errors on your php functions like getfooter/getheaders or check that file name is having .php extension.[image]

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem it was in wordpress where each page need to have its own template if its different of other pages. 
so i changed these line :

```
<?php
        /*
        Template Name: leb_army_sites
        */

        get_header();
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
        });
      }

      function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert(status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

```css
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
```

```html
 <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
```